# How to avoid race condition with 2 observable subscribers?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm trying to achieve a consistent call of 1 observable in several different places in my app. 
So, I wrote some example and I can't do this successfully.

```
private fun runTest() {
        val rs1 = requestResponse("rs1")
        val rs2 = requestResponse("rs2")

                //This works as should, but I can't create chains    
                //rs1.flatMap { rs2 }.repeat(5).subscribeBy()

                //This is not working
        rs1.repeat(5).subscribeBy()
        rs2.repeat(5).subscribeBy()
    }

private fun requestResponse(title: String): Single<Unit> =
                 doRequest(title)
                     .flatMap { readResponse(title) }



private fun doRequest(title: String): Single<Unit> {
        return Single
            .just(Unit)
            .doOnSuccess { Log.d("TEST", "$title --->") }
            .delay(Random.nextLong(500), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }

private fun readResponse(title: String): Single<Unit> {
                return Single
            .just(Unit)
            .doOnSuccess { Log.d("TEST", "$title <---") }
            .delay(Random.nextLong(500), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
```

So, I have tried to use `share` operator and make `requestResponse` return `ConnectableObservable` but it doesn't work anyway

I tried to use `Schedulers.single()` scheduler to make job in sigle thread and achieve a queue.

So, as the result I expecting to see in logs. It works with `flatMap`:

```
rs1 --->
rs1 <---
rs2 --->
rs2 <---
...
rs1 --->
rs1 <---
rs2 --->
rs2 <---
```

But I see

```
rs2 --->
rs1 --->
rs1 <---
rs2 <---
...
rs2 --->
rs1 --->
rs2 <---
rs1 <---
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rs1.repeat(5).blockingSubscribe()
rs2.repeat(5).blockingSubscribe()
```